# Problem with table in IE8/IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, doctype

So our site was designed without a doctype, and I'm trying to update it so that it's not forcing IE into quirks mode.
The problem is, there are a few tables that were using rounded corner images since the devs didn't understand how to use a div-based design. This looks normal in quirks mode and even IE7 mode, but when I use IE8 or IE9 standards mode, some of the rows in the table end up being taller than they should (namely the rows that contain the rounded corner images) and no amount of forced height seems to work. Is there some basic table display method I'm missing? This looks fine in all browsers EXCEPT IE8 and IE9, which to me is baffling. I've copied the code (with fully qualified image links) to jsbin, and you can view it here:
http://jsbin.com/ofedet/

I know the best method is to go ahead and replace these with divs or some other semantic element with border-radius, but for the time being I was hoping to just fix these issues to stave off disaster until I can convince them of the ROI of a redesign.

Comment: A screenshot of how it is supposed to look would be helpful.

Comment: +1 for making the effort to fix a site to stop it using quirksmode!

Comment: It looks like the problem is resolved, but the way it's supposed to look is how it looks in every other browser in the jsbin preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let those images float.

```
#Table_01 img { 
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: In non-strict mode, images are by default [block](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) elements. In strict mode, images are by default [inline](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html) elements (and thus standing on the same baseline as characters, causing them to appear "higher" than intended, leaving a spooky bottom padding). You could also make it `display: block;` so that the non-strict behaviour is simulated, but floating them is IMO better when you really want to be strict.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought it had to do with a display mode issue between the two, but my assumption was that it lied in the table and not the contents of the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS:

```
#Table_01 a img { border:0; margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a theory: my IE Dev Toolbar crapped out on me so I couldn't try it. Glad to see you got it working though.

Comment: hehe same happened with me when trying to test it, which is why I finally just threw it up on jsbin so people could hack away there. Thanks for your offer to help though!

Comment: Those are already the defaults for `<img>`, so it indeed won't change anything.